# ReactJS use a token stored in a function in a class that extends React.Component

Tags: reactjs

I am using tokens around my ReactJS application. This is how I can get the value of the token in a page:

**pages/Profile.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import useToken from '../useToken';

export default function Profile() {
  // Get token
  const { token, setToken } = useToken();
  const { userObject } = useToken();

  return(
    <div>
      <p>
      <b>Name:</b> {userObject?.name}<br />
      <b>Email:</b> {userObject?.email}<br />
      <b>Token:</b> {token}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I want to use the token inside a component. However the same appoch did not work, as it gives me an error "*Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)*".

**components/MyKnownDevices.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import useToken from '../useToken';

export default class MyKnownDevices extends React.Component {
  // Get token
  const { token, setToken } = useToken(); // <---- THIS GIVES ERROR
  const { userObject } = useToken(); // <---- THIS GIVES ERROR

  // Respone handler
  state = {
    myKnownDevices: []
  }

  // Call API
  componentDidMount() {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      }
    }
    
    let data = {
      'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': 'no',
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }

    axios.get('https://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users/get_my_known_devices', data, config)
      .then(res => {
        const myKnownDevices = res.data;
        this.setState({ myKnownDevices });
      })
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.myKnownDevices
          .map((device, index) => {
            return ( 
              <li key={index}>
                <span>{device.known_device_updated_timestamp_saying}</span>
              </li>
            );
           }
          )
        }
      </ul>
    )
  };
};
```

**useToken.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

// const userObject =  null;

export default function useToken() {

  // Get token
  const getToken = () => {
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return userToken 
  };

  // Consts
  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());
  const [userObject, setUserObject] = useState(null);

  // Effect
  useEffect(() => {
    if(token && token !== "undefined" && !userObject){
      setUserObject(jwt_decode(token));
     }
   },[token]);

  // Save token
  const saveToken = userToken => {
    if(userToken === null){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      setToken(null);
    }
    else{
      localStorage.setItem('token', userToken.token);
      setToken(userToken.token);
    }
  };

  // Return value
  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token,
    userObject, 
  }
}
```

How can I get the value of the token inside my component MyKnownDevices.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue here is that useToken is a hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and hooks can only be used in functional components.

Given your code, I think the simplest way would be to rewrite your class component as a functional component, this should do the trick :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import useToken from "../useToken";

export default function MyKnownDevices() {
  // Get token
  const { token, setToken, userObject } = useToken();
  const [myKnownDevices, setMyKnownDevices] = useState([]);

  // Call API
  // This is the same thing as your componentDitMount
  useEffect(() => {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    };

    let data = {
      HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE: "no",
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    };

    axios
      .get(
        "https://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users/get_my_known_devices",
        data,
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const myKnownDevices = res.data;
        setMyKnownDevices(myKnownDevices);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {myKnownDevices.map((device, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <span>{device.known_device_updated_timestamp_saying}</span>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not use react hooks inside class components. You should rewrite your class component to functional